# Enable passwordless sudo as a specific user

Tags: sudo

I have two users on my system: `itsadok`, my main user, and `elasticsearch`, a user with a different ulimit for running ElasticSearch.

I would like to be able to run stuff as the secondary user without being prompted for password every time.

I added the following line to `/etc/sudoers`:

```
itsadok ALL=(elasticsearch:elasticsearch) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

The way I understand it, this should allow the user itsadok, on any host, to run any command as (user or group) elasticsearch without a password. However, trying something like

```
itsadok@dev001$ sudo -u elasticsearch ls
```

prompts me for a password. Restarting the machine did not help.

What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE**:

It turns our that the order of lines in `sudoers` is significant. I placed the line under "User privilege specification" which sounded like the right place, but the line for the `%admin` group that comes later was overriding the setting.

Putting the same line at the end of the sudoers file fixed the issue.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Revised answer from comments: If you place directives below `#includedir`, they are ignored. Move the line next to the `sudo` or `admin`group definitions, or place it in separate file in `/etc/sudoers.d/`.

Comment: Didn't work. Also, the file already had a `root ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL` with no spaces around the colon, so it doesn't seem right. Just to be safe, I tried just `(elasticsearch)`. Doesn't work.

Comment: You are correct, it works without whitespace in 12.10 at least. Which Ubuntu you are using and exactly where in `sudoers` you place this line? I have faint recollection that if on older systems you placed the line after first `#includedir`, it got ignored. If it is at the end of file, try inserting it above the includedir.

Comment: Your comment set me on the right track: the order of the entries matters. Later settings override earlier settings.

Answer (score 19):

Follow these steps:

1. Edit sudoers file (this can be present in /etc/sudoers.d/file_name)

```
sudo visudo -f /etc/sudoers
```

2. Add line at the end of the file

```
usernameusedforlogin ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL
```

3. Save file

```
esc :wq!
```

Comment: This allows the user to run all commands on all hosts without passwords as any user, but it does not grant any group privileges, which was part of the original question. Generally, this is bad advice as you're giving the user very broad privileges.

Comment: as of 2022, this is the standard way.

Answer (score 0):

Alternately you can use python pudo package: https://pypi.org/project/pudo/1.0.0/

Installation:

```
user$ sudo -H pip3 install pudo # you can install using pip2 also
```

Below is the code snippit for using in python automation for running cmds under root privilege::

```
user$ python3 # or python2
>>> import pudo
>>> (ret, out) = pudo.run(('ls', '/root')) # or pudo.run('ls /root')
>>> print(ret)
>>> 0
>>> print(out)
>>> b'Desktop\nDownloads\nPictures\nMusic\n'
```

Below is the cmd example for running cmds under root privilege

```
user$ pudo ls /root
Desktop  Downloads  Pictures  Music
```

Comment: Please do not repost the same answer to many questions - if the questions are similar to each other enough so that they're duplicates, flag them as duplicates instead.  Thank you!