# Selectively enable sudo without password

Tags: sudo

On my Ubuntu system I followed the [instructions for enabling sudo without a password](https://askubuntu.com/questions/147241/execute-sudo-without-password).

It is working well, or should I say too well.

I have a couple of users, say userA and userB, who have been added to the sudo group.

```
sudo usermod -aG sudo userA
sudo usermod -aG sudo userB
```

I did `sudo visudo` and I added the following line at the bottom (i.e. the very last line):
`userA ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL`

However, I am finding that sudo without password is enabled for both userA and userB.

---

**Question:** How can I enable sudo without password for userA, but not userB?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Enable passwordless sudo as a specific user](https://askubuntu.com/questions/239432/enable-passwordless-sudo-as-a-specific-user)

Answer (score 0):

If, as you have done, the users are in the `sudo` group, they'll match the more general `%sudo` pattern in the `sudoers` file, and never see the `UserA` or `UserB` lines.

If you want fine-grained control, remove both `UserA` and `UserB` from the `sudo` group.

```
sudo deluser --system UserA sudo
sudo deluser --system UserB sudo
```

Read `man sudoers deluser`.